# Set .aspx page title to that of an Eval

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to use an `<%# Eval("name") %>` to be the title of my page. I can't seem to figure out any solutions online. I have tried the other StackOverflow question but that did now work either.

The page is a bio.aspx and on the site it is displayed as bio.aspx?id=123 so the page title needs to vary depending on the ID. I figured I could just use the Eval("name") but no luck yet.

I currently am using JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.title = '<%# Eval("name") %> | Title Line';
}
```

This works, but it still leaves the title tags empty, and it's kind of spammy.

Here is the codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class DoctorBio : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Your Page Title";

    HtmlMeta metaDescription = new HtmlMeta();
    metaDescription.Name = "description";
    metaDescription.Content = "brief description";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaDescription);

    HtmlMeta metaKeywords = new HtmlMeta();
    metaKeywords.Name = "keywords";
    metaKeywords.Content = "keywords, keywords";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKeywords);
}
protected void SetPageTitle(object title)
{
this.Title = title.ToString();
}
protected string ReplaceLineBreaks(object text)
{
    string newText = text as string;
    if (newText == null) { return string.Empty; }
    return newText.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
}
}
```

Comment: <%# Eval() %> will only be valid within a databinding operation and it is unlikely to make much sense since in your case, title is a single entity. Also, why do your method signatures require objects and then you convert them to strings? Just use a string parameter. Lots of confusion here.

Comment: this.Title = title.ToString() is correct, the error is somehwere else...

Comment: @user1860529 I don't see anywhere in your code that you are 1) calling the method `SetPageTitle` or 2) actually data-binding anything (loading bio ID 123, etc).  When are you expecting that the page's title actually gets set?

Comment: @user1860529 Sorry to ask you, but i was not able to find 'name' property in your code which is used in eval.@Mike,today is my first day and I was not clear where to put my message.Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following code
**Previous code**

```
this.Title = title.ToString();
```

**Replace with**

```
Page.Title = title.ToString();
```

Try this one. It is working for me...

Comment: I am obviously not very comfortable with this. I tried the above solution and it didn't work.     In an effort to better explain myself I guess if you were to go to bio.aspx?ID=2 the "name" would be Mike. I can permanently set the page title to Mike, but when I go to bio.aspx?ID=3 the title will remain Mike even if that "name" is John. I am looking for a way to get the document title to read the "name" from the sqldatasource.

Comment: Specify me how you set page title and on which controls's which event you are going to make this type of changes.......
It will be very helpful for both of us buddy....